# Allowing for a variable number of return values in method declaration

Tags: go

I have a function that solves the problem of Go not allowing for the setting of default values in method declarations. I want to make it just a little bit better by allowing for a variable number of return variables. I understand that I can allow for an array of interfaces as a return type and then create an interface array with all the variables to return, like this:

```
func SetParams(params []interface{}, args ...interface{}) (...[]interface{}) {
    var values []interface{}
    for i := range params {
            var value interface{}
            paramType := reflect.TypeOf(params[i])
            if len(args) < (i + 1) {
                    value = params[i]
            } else {
                    argType := reflect.TypeOf(args[i])
                    if paramType != argType {
                            value = params[i]
                    }
                    value = args[i]
            }
            values = append(values, value)
    }

    return values
}
```

This is an example of a method you want to define default values for. You build it as a variadic function (allowing a variable number of parameters) and then define the default values of the specific params you are looking for inside the function instead of in the declaration line.

```
func DoSomething(args ...interface{}) {
    //setup default values
    str := "default string 1"
    num := 1
    str2 := "default string 2"


    //this is fine
    values := SetParams([]interface{str, num, str2}, args)
    str = values[0].(string)
    num = values[1].(int)
    str = values[2].(string)


    //I'd rather support this
    str, num, str2 = SetParams(params, args)
}
```

I understand that

> []interface{str, num, str2}

in the above example is not syntactically correct. I did it that way to simplify my post. But, it represents another function that builds the array of interfaces.

I would like to support this:

```
str, num, str2 = SetParams(params, args)
```

instead of having to do this:

```
values := SetParams([]interface{str, num, str2}, args)
str = values[0].(string)
num = values[1].(int)
str = values[2].(string)
```

Any advice? Help?

Comment: Go is a compiled language, not a scripting language, so there are only so many things you can do to make it look "dynamic".

Comment: I'm aware of that. That wasn't my question or a valid answer.

Comment: That's why I put it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You could pass your "args" by reference instead.

Answer (score 8):

Please don't write horrible (and ineffective due to `reflect`) code to solve nonexistent problem.
As was indicated in comments, turning a language into
one of your previous languages is indeed compelling
after a switch, but this is counterproductive.

Instead, it's better to work with the idioms and approaches
and best practices the language provides --
even if you don't like them (yet, maybe).

For this particular case you can roll like this:

- Make the function which wants to accept
  a list of parameters with default values
  accept a single value of a custom `struct` type.
- For a start, any variable of such type, when allocated,
  has all its fields initialized with the so-called "zero values"
  appropriate to their respective types.

  If that's enough, you can stop there: you will be able
  to pass values of your `struct` type to your functions
  by producing them via literals right at the call site --
  initializing only the fields you need.

  Otherwise have pre-/post- processing code which
  would provide your own "zero values" for the fields
  you need.

**Update on 2016-08-29:**

Using a `struct` type to simulate optional parameters
using its fields being assigned default values which happen
to be Go's native zero values for their respective data types:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type params struct {
    foo string
    bar int
    baz float32
}

func myfun(params params) {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", params)
}

func main() {
    myfun(params{})
    myfun(params{bar: 42})
    myfun(params{foo: "xyzzy", baz: 0.3e-2})
}
```

outputs:

```
main.params{foo:"", bar:0, baz:0}
main.params{foo:"", bar:42, baz:0}
main.params{foo:"xyzzy", bar:0, baz:0.003}
```

As you can see, Go initializes the fields of our `params` type
with the zero values appropriate to their respective types
unless we specify our own values when we define our literals.

[Playground link.](https://play.golang.org/p/sbwOI3kucG)

Providing default values which are not Go-native zero values for
the fields of our custom type can be done by either pre-
or post-processing the user-submitted value of a compound type.

Post-processing:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type params struct {
    foo string
    bar int
    baz float32
}

func (pp *params) setDefaults() {
    if pp.foo == "" {
        pp.foo = "ahem"
    }
    if pp.bar == 0 {
        pp.bar = -3
    }
    if pp.baz == 0 { // Can't really do this to FP numbers; for demonstration purposes only
        pp.baz = 0.5
    }
}

func myfun(params params) {
    params.setDefaults()
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", params)
}

func main() {
    myfun(params{})
    myfun(params{bar: 42})
    myfun(params{foo: "xyzzy", baz: 0.3e-2})
}
```

outputs:

```
main.params{foo:"ahem", bar:-3, baz:0.5}
main.params{foo:"ahem", bar:42, baz:0.5}
main.params{foo:"xyzzy", bar:-3, baz:0.003}
```

[Playground link.](https://play.golang.org/p/RhliDk8sZP)

Pre-processing amounts to creating a "constructor" function
which would return a value of the required type pre-filled
with the default values your choice for its fields—something
like this:

```
func newParams() params {
    return params{
        foo: "ahem",
        bar: -3,
        baz: 0.5,
    }
}
```

so that the callers of your function could call `newParams()`,
tweak its fields if they need and then pass the resulting value
to your function:

```
myfunc(newParams())

ps := newParams()
ps.foo = "xyzzy"
myfunc(ps)
```

This approach is maybe a bit more robust than post-processing but
it precludes using of literals to construct the values to pass to
your function right at the call site which is less "neat".

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: @JonStevens, here it is; sorry for the delay.

Comment: If one of the properties of the params struct was a bool and you wanted to default it to true if nothing was passed, how would you handle if someone actually passed a false? Wouldn't it treat it as a bool zero-value?

Comment: @JonStevens, but how does that matter? I mean, if you need to record the fact the user *explicitly* set some value -- no matter whether it was the same as the zero-value for its underlying type or not -- you're rather dealing with the case where you need to deal with that "a variable has no value" case (like `NULL` in SQL databases or `undefined` in JavaScript or `null` of .NET's "nullable types" etc).

Comment: @JonStevens, Go does not support such `NULL`/`undefined` values directly for its types, so you have to use one of available devices to provide something similar. One approach is to use a pointer to a value rather than the value directly: since the zero value for a pointer of any type is `nil`, and it's defined to not point to anything valid, this can be used to signify the absence of a value; say, if you define a field of your `struct` type to be `*bool` then if the user wants to actually provide a value, they assign a pointer to some vlue of type `bool` to that field...

Comment: @JonStevens, ...and if they provide nothing the field has the value `nil`. The upside of this approach is that it's reasonably straightforward. The downsides are more pressure on the GC and `panic()s` in cases when you would blindly dereference that pointer w/o checking it for `!= nil` first. Another approach is using a separate (boolean) flag meaning "that field was set". A refinement of this approach is using a custom type like `type BoolNull struct { Value bool; Valid bool }` with the same semantics: `Value`'s value is only valid if `Valid == true`...

Comment: @JonStevens, ... A nice property of `bool`'s zero value makes sure such boolean flags start life being `false` thus making sure values not initialized explicitly are automatically "invalid". Hope this helps. BTW you can see the latter approach implemented in the Go standard library: [`NullBool`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullBool) et al.

Comment: @JonStevens, oh, and in case I've misinterpreted your comment on the first read, the "pre-processing" or "constructor" approach (the third in my example) deals with this case: you provide the user with a function constructing an instance of such "params" struct pre-filled with whatever data you wants to be the defaults. The user is then free to change whatever fields they want and pass the resulting value to the function.

Comment: @JonStevens, and particularly with booleans, there's another approach: just make the value have "reversed" semantics and treat it as such. To demonstrate, if you have a variable named `DoThat` and want it default to `true` so that the user is able to explicitly tell your function "don't do that", then renaming the variable to `DontDoThat` and defaulting it to `false` solves the problem: if the user does not explicitly set it to `true` it defaults to `false` which is semantically the same as `!DoThat`.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was playing with anonymous functions in Go and implemented an example which accepts and returns undefined parameters:

```
func functions() (funcArray []func(args ... interface{}) (interface{}, error)) {

    type ret struct{
        first   int
        second  string
        third   bool
    }

    f1 := func(args ... interface{}) (interface{}, error){
        a := args[0].(int)
        b := args[1].(int)
        return (a < b), nil
    }
    funcArray = append(funcArray , f1)

    f2 := func(args ... interface{}) (interface{}, error){
        return (args[0].(string) + args[1].(string)), nil
    }
    funcArray = append(funcArray , f2)

    f3 := func(args ... interface{}) (interface{}, error){
        return []int{1,2,3}, nil
    }
    funcArray = append(funcArray , f3)

    f4 := func(args ... interface{}) (interface{}, error){
        return ret{first: 1, second: "2", third: true} , nil
    }
    funcArray = append(funcArray , f4)

    return funcArray 
}


func main() {

    myFirst_Function := functions()[0]
    mySecond_Function := functions()[1]
    myThird_Function := functions()[2]
    myFourth_Function := functions()[3]

    fmt.Println(myFirst_Function(1,2))
    fmt.Println(mySecond_Function("1","2"))
    fmt.Println(myThird_Function())
    fmt.Println(myFourth_Function ())

}
```

I hope it helps you.

https://play.golang.org/p/d6dSYLwbUB9